# How to evaluate double integral with variable upper limit of inner integral

Tags: python, scipy, symbolic-math, numerical-integration, numerical-computing

I am trying to evaluate a double integral in which the limit of the inner integral is variable and depends on the outer integral. Coming from Matlab background, it is easy by using symbolic integration, but I have no idea how to calculate the same in Python in an efficient way. I read  `scipy` documents but didn't get anything helpful.  An example of such an integral is

[image: Equation]

Any help regarding the same would be very appreciated.

Update: I am looking for a numerical solution to the problem. Thanks a lot for the answers and help. They make complete sense. I have an updated question. I want to evaluate the following integral, which is an updated version of above. Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you want a symbolic solution or a numerical solution?

Comment: @Tarik I want a numerical solution.

Answer (score 3):

To compute a double integral, you can use the function [scipy.integrate.dblquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html). Or you can use the function [scipy.integrate.quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) twice.

The example integrals can be done like the following:

```py
import math
from scipy.integrate import dblquad, quad
from scipy.special import erf, jv


def h(t, z):
    return f(t) * g(z)


def f(t):
    return 0.5 * t * (erf(t - a) - 1) * jv(0, q * t)


def g(z):
    return math.exp(-((z - a) ** 2)/(2 * (s ** 2)))


def h1(z):
    return integral_of_f(z) * g(z)


def h2(z):
    return (integral_of_f(z) ** 2) * g(z)


def integral_of_f(z):
    return quad(f, 0, 2 * z)[0]  # here abserr is discarded


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, q, s = 0, 2, 3  # set the constants

    result, abserr = dblquad(h, 0, 60, lambda z: 0, lambda z: 2 * z)
    print(f'result: {result}, abserr: {abserr}')

    result1 = quad(h1, 0, 60)[0]  # abserr here for result1 is not valid since abserr is already discarded in the function integral_of_f
    print(f'result1: {result1}')

    result2 = quad(h2, 0, 60)[0]  # abserr here for result2 is not valid too for the same reason
    print(f'result2: {result2}')
```

which prints

```
result: -0.21705286423629183, abserr: 1.4361242750875712e-08
result1: -0.21705286423678177
result2: 0.013105371081178754
```

You can see that `result`, which is computed by using `dblquad`, and `result1`, which is computed by using `quad` twice, are almost the same value, because they computed the same integral.

`result2` is for the updated question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This makes perfect sense. Can you help me with one more thing? Please see the edited question. I would be very thankful.

Comment: @Shankar_Dutt You’re welcome:) I updated my answer.